# {Py}Gradle build no module name testrepository

Tags: python, python-3.x, gradle

I'm new with gradle and i would like to create a gradle project with python, i follow the guide write [here](https://attx-project.github.io/Building-with-Gradle.html) and I create the project. 
The installation doens't give me any problem but when i run the project with the command

```
gradle build
```

Give me this error:

```
   ..
Install pbr-0.11.0 .................................................. [STARTING]
    Processing /home/.../.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/pypi/pbr/0.11.0/72801e9ffd52e7f438422a3e08b578e906cd270a/pbr-0.11.0.tar.gz
        Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
        Traceback (most recent call last):
          File "<string>", line 20, in <module>
          File "/tmp/pip-f2i4gbg4-build/setup.py", line 22, in <module>
            **util.cfg_to_args())
          File "/tmp/pip-f2i4gbg4-build/pbr/util.py", line 261, in cfg_to_args
            wrap_commands(kwargs)
          File "/tmp/pip-f2i4gbg4-build/pbr/util.py", line 482, in wrap_commands
            for cmd, _ in dist.get_command_list():
          File "/home/IASuserdev/Desktop/gradleFun/pythonGradle/build/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/setuptools/dist.py", line 507, in get_command_list
            cmdclass = ep.resolve()
          File "/home/IASuserdev/Desktop/gradleFun/pythonGradle/build/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2297, in resolve
            module = __import__(self.module_name, fromlist=['__name__'], level=0)
          File "/tmp/pip-f2i4gbg4-build/pbr/testr_command.py", line 47, in <module>
            from testrepository import commands
        ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'testrepository'

        ----------------------------------------
    Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-f2i4gbg4-build


    FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

    * What went wrong:
    Execution failed for task ':installTestRequirements'.
    > Failed to install pbr-0.11.0. Please see above output for reason, or re-run your build using ``gradle -i build`` for additional logging.

    * Try:
    Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
```

I try to install testrepository with pip inside the virtual environment then i clean and rebuild the project but it's the same.
I read another question and try all the answers but nothing works, can someone help me?

Answer (score 0):

I uncommented theselines in `setup.py` and it works fine now.

```
setup(
   distclass=GradleDistribution,
   package_dir={'': 'src'},
   packages=find_packages('src'),
   include_package_data=True,

   entry_points={
       'console_scripts': [
           'hello_world = foo.hello:main',
       ],
   }
)
```

Answer (score 0):

see comment on [pygradle issue #246 (Install Requirements Fails, bad pbr version)](https://github.com/linkedin/pygradle/issues/246#issuecomment-429478473) it helps for me and looks like it`s you case.

in general:

> This is not pygradle issue, but we know from experience that pbr can cause issues for people

so just try fix it customize pygradle configuration(add **pbr** to **setupRequires**) for example like this:

```
dependencies {
    setupRequires 'pypi:pbr:5.1.1'
}
```